# JUnit java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-8, junit, connectexception

I'm pretty new in Java, so don't be rude ;-)
I got a task to do and there are some JUnit-Tests to verify my solution.
When I'm trying to run them, it takes some time and then I get the following errors:

```
Could not connect to:  : 51219          
java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.connect(RemoteTestRunner.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here's what I use:

- Windows 8
- JRE 7
- JUnit 4
- Eclipse Classic 4.2.1

Can you help me with this?

Comment: pls share the code, where it actually throws the exception.

Comment: The setup does not seems to be complete. Is your remote runner ready?

Comment: @R.J the error occurs for every JUnit test, also for a small example test case.

Comment: @Jayan That's odd.. do I have do set something up for JUnit? In the past, I never had to set up anything special for JUnit... How do I set up the remote runner?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Unit test is trying to connect to port 51219 which is not possible on your local machine.
Try to start a local server, or "mock" the server connection.

Comment: But why does JUnit need to connect to a port? And how do I "mock" the server connection?
Past JUnit tests I ran always worked without setup...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else encountering the same issue:
There seems to be a problem with the JRE 7 in Windows 8.
Using JRE 6 solves the problem! :)